# Error deserializing Dictionary<TKey,TValue> after changes on class TKey

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, datacontractserializer

If been serializing a generic dictionary, straightforward like this:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true });
    var objectType = typeof(T);
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(objectType);
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, objectToSerialize);
    writer.Close();
}
```

where T is `Dictionary<DataSource, bool>`. `DataSource` is a custom type. Now I worked on the class `DataSource` and made some changes, *without changing the DataContract or properties involved in serialization*.

Now, I a cannot deserialize the XML anymore and get the following exception:

> Error in line 1 position 163. Expecting element
>   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfDataSourcebooleanClMIOMsG' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'..
>   Encountered 'Element'  with name
>   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfDataSourcebooleandM5BGXus', namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'.

My questions are:

- Where does the ID in the type name come from ("CIMIOMsG')?
- Why did it change?
- What can I do to deserialize my old files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake: I changed the namespace of the class `DataSource` (must have been a reflex triggered by ReSharper...). Changing the namespace to the original version fixed it. The id seems to be a namespace hash.